# Is Azure SQL trigger for Functions is generally available for SQL Server hosted on Azure VM

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-functions

I see that the Azure SQL trigger is now generally available on Azure SQL Database.

Here is the link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/general-availability-azure-sql-updates-for-latejanuary-2024/

Is it also generally available for SQL Server hosted on Azure VM?

Comment: Is Azure SQL Trigger generally available for SQL Server hosted on Azure VM?

Comment: As per the article is available for Azure SQL Database, it is no where mentioned that is available for SQL Server on Azure VM

Comment: Check this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/954684/azure-function-app-interact-with-sql-virtual-machi) if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is the link to the answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1602107/is-azure-sql-trigger-for-functions-is-generally-av)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution @*[AnuragSingh-MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/954684/azure-function-app-interact-with-sql-virtual-machi)*.

As mentioned in the above MSDOC Q&A, **Azure SQL trigger for Functions is available for SQL Server hosted on Azure VM**.

1. Create a Virtual Machine with SQL Server Image.

[image]

2. Go to SQL Server Settings, Select Public(Internet) in the SQL Connectivity and note the port for further use.
3. Enable SQL Authentication and `Review+Create`.

[image]

1. Navigate to Overview of VM, copy the **Public IP address** of your SQL Server VM.
2. Open SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), go to connect=>**Connect to Database Engine**, enter VM's public IP address with port (1433, which was specified during the creation of VM) in the **Server name** field. For example,  `11.22.33.444,1401`.
3. In the **Authentication** section, select **SQL Server Authentication**, enter *username and password* and **Connect**.
4. Connect to the VM remotely using RDP.

[image]

Refer [Connect to SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/sql-vm-create-portal-quickstart?view=azuresql#connect-to-sql-server) MSDOC to ensure that you are able to connect to SQL Server with these values.

5. Once you are able to connect to the SQL DB from SQL Server Management Studio, Refer [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-ver16), to use these values to **create Connection URL and use it in the Azure Function**.

**General form of connection URL:**

> jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]